# Could not decode main.cpp with UTF-8 ecoding

Tags: c++, macos, qt, utf-8, character-encoding

I got a Visual Studio Qt/C++ project (from China, not sure if this matters so mentioning here because Chinese characters are a little tricky sometimes). When I open it on QtCreator (my preferred IDE) on macOS (my preferred OS) then I get

```
Could not decode main.cpp with UTF-8 ecoding. Editing not possible.
```

If I click `Select Encoding` and choose `System` then I can edit normally. I can even save and close the file but when I open it again same thing happen.

I noticed there are some comments appearing as `)//??????????????????` and `//???????�??????????UI` which seems to be a problem related to enconding.

How to deal with this issue?

What the `System` encoding means?

Openning the file on SublimeText and Save with Encoding UTF8 seems to solve the problem. But I have a lot of files, any suggestion on how to do it from command line for all files?
[image]

And the file seems not to be UTF8:

```
$ file main.cpp
main.cpp: c program text, ISO-8859 text
```

Finally I went to QtCreator, Tools, Options, Text Editor, Behavior, File Encodings and set Default Encoding to ISO-8859-1. Now there is no more complains on QtCretor side. Are there any downsides on doing this?

Comment: You can inspect the system encoding by typing `locale` in the terminal.

Comment: If the source code would contain plain ASCII exclusively (no character with code point > 127) then the difference between ASCII and UTF-8 could not be detected. (UTF-8 and ASCII are identical concerning the first 128 code-points. That was intended.) I would strip the resp. characters from that source and it shouldn't you bother anymore. (I guess you cannot read Chinese comments even if they are printed correctly?)

Comment: You mean to edit file manually? I have too many files to go and edit them all. Any suggesstion on how to automate this?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe, bash/sed or bash/awk or even bash/Python? There is also this `tr` command on Unix which could be of help. (You could write a helper program in C++ if you are not familiar with any of the above. It's probably a 10-liner.) ;-)

Comment: Comments that appear garbled mean that the original file author has used a different encoding. There is no good way to determine which one, except to try several encodings and see if you get something that makes sense. You can re-encode files with the `iconv` command but you need to know the source encoding.

Comment: Localized versions of Windows have a default encoding.  In the US it is `Windows-1252`, but in China it is something else.  There are command line switches to the compiler such as `/source-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn set source character set` (see the compiler help, e.g. `cl /?`) that can specify the source file encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it contains non-valid UTF-8 characters. [Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/97636/qtcreator-error-could-not-decode-with-utf-8-editing-not-possible/5) is a question with the same problem on Qt forum. One of the comments says

> I just discovered this because a header file from FTDI contained a copyright symbol. I just converted that to read (C) instead of the copyright symbol and it was fine.

You can try that. If it's not that, I advise you to check if it is valid UTF-8 text. You can check if it is valid UTF-8 with a command like: `iconv -f UTF-8 your_file > /dev/null; echo $?`, it will return `0` if it is valid and `1` if it is not valid.

Comment: The online tool suggested says "Import successful!
main.cpp (2.51KB) imported as plain text." I guess that means its a valid UTF8.

Comment: Can you please try the command? It is far better and I think the online tool suggested previously doesn't always work, I just tested a file on both and the online tool says it's okay while the command says it is not. Try checking your file with the command I edited my answer with.